# How do I replace filtering an object with each & if

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

At the moment my code works, however it's very slow. The issue is with filtering object visits at the moment I'm going trough every item of visits and showing output based on `if`.

Would it be faster to use `visits.filter` ? If yes. How to tweak my function? Thanks

```
chrome.history.search(options, function(history) {
    $.each(history, function(i, item) {
        var itemTime = new Date(item.lastVisitTime)

        if (item.visitCount > 0) {
            $.each(history, function(i, item) {
                chrome.history.getVisits({ url: item.url }, function(visits) {

                    $.each(visits, function(i, visit) {

                        if (visit.visitTime > startTime && visit.id == item.id) {
                            var visiTime = new Date(visit.visitTime)
                            //console.log(visit)
                            console.log(visiTime + ' ' + item.url)
                        }

                    })
                })
            })
        } else {
            console.debug(itemTime + ' ' + item.url)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop history twice inside each other? That certainly makes things slower

Comment: Yes, because this are two different APIs if the visitCount in the first one is > 0 you have to call getVisits API the problem is the visits API shows all ate ranges again for the particular URL so I need quickly narrow it dow to the dates specified before.

Comment: I'm sure it could easily be changed into a single loop and that would make it faster. Now you're doing multiple calls to getVisits() for the same URL.

Comment: I can share you my full code if you like to try?